# Make TextField in libGDX java

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx

I've got problem with making TextField in my libGDX project. So I just take some compleate example of initialize Label from web. And it's work well.

```
     public ItemCreateScreen()
{
     Label.LabelStyle Label1Style = new Label.LabelStyle();
    BitmapFont myFont = new BitmapFont();
    myFont.scale(2);
    Label1Style.font = myFont;
    Label1Style.fontColor = Color.RED;


    Label Label1 = new Label("Title (BitmapFont)",Label1Style);
    Label1.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),row_height);
    Label1.setPosition(0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-row_height*2);
    Label1.setText("Hello folks");
    mLabels.add(Label1);
}

@Override
public void drawn(SpriteBatch fBatch)
{
    mLabels.get(0).draw(fBatch,255);
}
```

When i just replace textually "Label" with "TextField", and feel great because compilation isnt show any error.

```
      public ItemCreateScreen()
{
    TextField.TextFieldStyle TextField1Style = new 
    TextField.TextFieldStyle();
    BitmapFont myFont = new BitmapFont();
    myFont.scale(2);
    TextField1Style.font = myFont;
    TextField1Style.fontColor = Color.RED;

    TextField TextField1 = new TextField("Title (BitmapFont)",TextField1Style);
    TextField1.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),row_height);
    TextField1.setPosition(0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-row_height*2);
    TextField1.setText("Hello folks");
    mTextFields.add(TextField1);
}

@Override
public void drawn(SpriteBatch fBatch)
{
    mTextFields.get(0).draw(fBatch,255);
}
```

But after build i dont see any TextField like it was before with Label.
What i have done wrong?

Comment: Hmm, I'd suggest adding textures for the other style fields, but according to https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextField.TextFieldStyle.html they are optional.

Comment: So you have no idea what the reason of this print fail

Comment: Other than using those fields, they are all I need. You'd need to present a MWE for me to replicate the issue you are facing.